# Error in Reset password joomla 3.0

Tags: passwords, reset, joomla3.0

I am facing a problem in joomla 3.0 when i go to reset page after verify code url is ../index.php/registration?view=reset&layout=complete.

The scenario is: fill different values in password and conform password. Then submit form, the error is:

> Notice
>       Completing reset password failed: exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The passwords you entered do
>   not match. Please enter your desired password in the password field
>   and confirm your entry by entering it in the confirm password field.'
>   in
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/libraries/joomla/form/form.php:1872
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/libraries/joomla/form/form.php(1105):
>   JForm->validateField(Object(SimpleXMLElement), '', 'dfdefsdfdfdfdf',
>   Object(JRegistry)) #1
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/components/com_users/models/reset.php(122):
>   JForm->validate(Array) #2
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/components/com_users/controllers/reset.php(156):
>   UsersModelReset->processResetComplete(Array) #3
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(722): UsersControllerReset->complete() #4
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/components/com_users/users.php(15):
>   JControllerLegacy->execute('complete') #5
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/libraries/legacy/component/helper.php(359):
>   require_once('/home/fiable/pu...') #6
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/libraries/legacy/component/helper.php(339):
>   JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/home/fiable/pu...') #7
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/includes/application.php(205):
>   JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_users') #8
>   /home/fiable/public_html/projects/canvasfast/index.php(52):
>   JSite->dispatch() #9 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested in joomla 3.0 go to the line 130 components\com_users\models\reset.php

replace bellow code:

```
 // Check the validation results.
        if ($return === false) {
            // Get the validation messages from the form.
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $message) {
                $this->setError($message);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

to:

```
     // Check the validation results.
      if ($return === false) {
   $errors = $form->getErrors();
   for ($i = 0, $n = count($errors); $i < $n && $i < 3; $i++) {
    if ($errors[$i] instanceof Exception) {
     $this->setError($errors[$i]->getMessage());
    } else {
     $this->setError($errors[$i]);
    }
   }

   return false;
  }
```